# Meego 1.2 Harmattan and QCamera application

Tags: qt, nokia, qt-mobility, meego, meego-harmattan

Is there any way to work with camera with QCamera class in Nokia N9 (Meego 1.2 Harmattan) or I should use another one?

Here's my problem: simple application that works fine on Nokia C6-01 (Symbian Anna) doesn't do anything useful on N9.

Here're code snipets:

testmobile.pro

```
<...>
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += multimedia
LIBS += -lQtMultimediaKit
<...>
```

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    <...>
    private:
        QCamera* camera_;
        QGraphicsView *view;
        QGraphicsVideoItem *videoItem;
        QGraphicsScene *scene;
    <...>
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
<...>
    camera_ = new QCamera;
    view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(view);
    videoItem = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
    view->setScene(scene);
    scene->addItem(videoItem);

    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    lay->addWidget(view);
    this->setLayout(lay);
    view->show();
    camera_->setViewfinder(videoItem);

    camera_->start();
}

<...>
```

So after MainWindow object is constructed and shown we'll se a simple viewfinder on Nokia C6-01 and black screen on Nokia N9.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution!
It was security problem. As I found - Meego has analogue of "capabilities" of Symbian. It's called AEGIS security tokens.
So, to request a permission to work with camera (or any other) you should add your_application_name.agis file into the "qtc_packaging/debian_harmattan" folder of your project.
In my case this file consisted of:

```
<aegis>
    <request>
        <credential name="GRP::video"/>
        <credential name="GRP::pulse-access"/>
        <for path="/opt/testmobile/bin/testmobile"/>
   </request>
</aegis>
```

So permissons are defined in the "name" property of "credential" tag and "for path" tag defines package to perform these permissions with.

More information can be found [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Developing_for_Harmattan_Harmattan_security_Security_guide_Harmattan_APIs_that_require_credentials.html)